# AngularJs: How to initialize the value for function Which is returning NaN?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, nan, angularjs-controller

I had a problem on my code in angularJs function which is return NaN instead of 0 during initialization.

Sample Code is Here

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    
    
    $scope.finalNo = function(firstNo,secondNo) {
        
        var amount = firstNo*1 + secondNo*1;
        return amount;
    };
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

First No: <input type="text" ng-model="firstNo"><br>
Second No: <input type="text" ng-model="secondNo"><br>
<br>
<label ng-init="fullName(firstName,lastName) == 1 ">Final No: {{finalNo(firstNo,secondNo)}}</label>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

After you enter the firstNo and SecondNo, the finalNo displays the addition of 2 numbers. My problem is its initialized from NaN instead of 0. How to initialize from 0, also how to handle the NaN (ie,) in case of NaN, i want the value 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to parse it using `parseInt()` if no decimal points are allowed, if allowed use `.parseFloat()`

Comment: Have you tried `type="number"`, instead of `type="text"`? [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/706/built-in-directives/2354/angular-expressions-text-vs-number#t=201611210637470576282)

Comment: i also tried parseInt() but the function  value returning NaN while initializing.

Comment: @AlonEitan but i have to do it in type="text"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse it using [`.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and at the initial level models are not initialized so it will always return calculations resulting not a number (NaN), to avoid it `return amount || 0`

Hope this will help

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.finalNo = function(firstNo,secondNo) {
        
        var amount = parseInt(firstNo) * 1 + parseInt(secondNo) * 1;
        return amount || 0;
    };
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

First No: <input type="text" ng-model="firstNo"><br>
Second No: <input type="text" ng-model="secondNo"><br>
<br>
<label>Final No: {{finalNo(firstNo,secondNo)}}</label>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/AI19zaCn1IZMSGNjX6v3?p=preview)

Please change your script to below code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.finalNo = function(firstNo,secondNo) {
            var amount = parseInt(firstNo*1 + secondNo*1);
            return amount;
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
var amount = parseInt(firstNo) * 1 + parseInt(secondNo) * 1;
```